# Shooting in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a shooter in pygame. I am able to have the player move around, and when space is pressed, the bullet will go to its position. I am wondering how i can get it to move away from the player, until it hits the edge of the screen. Here is what i have so far:

```
if AMMO > 0:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and Gun.image == NOGUN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and Gun.image == NOGUN:
            Bullet.rect.center = Player.rect.center
            if Player.direction == 0:
                Bullet.direction = 0 #WHERE THE BULLET WILL MOVE

            shot.play()
            print "BANG"
            AMMO = AMMO - 1
            time.sleep(0.09)
```

Answer (score 3):

We'd need more code here.

In pseudocode:

```
def frameUpdate( timeBetweenFrame, bulletSpeed, playerDirectionVector ):
       bullet.position = bullet.position + playerDirectionVector.MultiplyByScalar(bulletSpeed * timeBetweenFrame);
```

Where playerDirectionVector is a normalized vector in the direction the player is facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if AMMO > 0:
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and Gun.image == NOGUN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and Gun.image == NOGUN:
        #Initialize Bullet so it's not null and do the rest
        Bullet.rect.center = Player.rect.center
        if Player.direction == 0:
            Bullet.direction = 0

 if Bullet != null
    Bullet.X += 10 
    if Bullet.X > ScreenWidth()
        Bullet = null 
#These are all examples so you can understand the logic, I don't remember exactly how pygame works, but since you can move a character around you can find this :P
```

Keep in mind that this code allows only one bullet!

Answer (score 0):

What I use when I make bullet instances in psudocode

```
#making your starting bullet cords
Bulletx = playerx
Bullety = playery
#this stores the angle the bullet was   shot from
Bulletangle = degreesplayerisrotated
```

This converts the angle to a radian
    Bulletangle = Bulletangle×pi/180

```
#this line updates the cords speed is a set value of how fast you want the bullet to move
Bulletx = bulletx-cos(bulletangle)×speed
Bullety = bullety-sin (bulletangle)×speed

Screen.blit (bullet, (bulletx, bullety))
```

Or draw a circle with the cords

If you have a question be sure to ask hope this cleared things up